# Two columns same height with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this [site](http://www.codetocode-developments.com/personal/) I have two columns and I want they to have the same height. This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var Height = $("#per-wrapper").height();
    $('#per-side-column').css("min-height", Height);
});
```

But, like you can see in the link, the height is not the same in the home page or the archives page, but is equal in single page.

I think it can be because some video or image that is render after jQuery is ready. Somebody know why?

Comment: You might wanna set your `#per-side-column` height same as `#per-index` instead!

Comment: Why do this with JavaScript when it can be done with pure CSS?

Comment: i try doing with css, but i can not.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem i added inline script tags

```
<script>
    var Height = $("#per-wrapper").height();
    $('#per-side-column').css("min-height", Height);
</script>
```

just before footer after `<section id = "#per-wrapper"></section>` close tag. This helps to get the height after the #per-wrapper is loaded and occupied the height required.

Comment: I have the same result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a javascript approach to set the minimum size of the left column to be the size of the right column, you have to wait until the content of right column has loaded meaning you have to delay setting the min-height.

Use the setTimeout function to delay calling a function.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
   var Height = $("#per-wrapper").height();
   $('#per-side-column').css("min-height", Height);
}, 1);
```

1 is the number of milliseconds to delay. You will need to adjust this value to suit your needs.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp